# Regular Expression all characters except last one

Tags: regex

This is my string: `50.00.00..00.00`

I want to match all `.` except the last one, so after a replace I end up with `50000000.00`

Can somebody help me with this?

Comment: Can you post the regex pattern your currently using?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

```
\.(?=.*\.)
```

Matches a dot (`\.`), which there must be another dot following it (`(?=.*\.)`).

(This assumes the regex engine supports [lookahead](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html), e.g. PCRE, Python, etc.)

Comment: Thank you this worked! I was trying so much with lookahead, could not get it working. Cheers!

Comment: Works fine with JavaScript. You can get your regex explained [here](http://rick.measham.id.au/paste/explain.pl?regex=%5C.%28%3F%3D.*%5C.%29)

Comment: Works fine with Java too.

Answer (score 3):

So you did not specified your regex tools, engine, etc. Well you can do this with e.g. `sed` (only work if there are always two digits after the last `dot` and the last `dot` is always present):

```
echo "50.00.00..00.00" | sed 's/\.//;s/\(..\)$/.\1/'
```

But there are several other ways, e.g. with lookahead regex (if it's supported for you).

HTH

Comment: Yes I should have mentioned that, I am using Java. And the answer of KennyTM worked for me. Thanks anyways!