# Regex - Remove all matches leaving the last

Tags: php, regex

I need a regex to remove dots in an number but just leaving the last. Example:

```
12312.123132.12312.131.3131.3123.13123.1231
```

to

```
12312123132123121313131312313123.1231
```

I tried some expressions but none worked.

Comment: Except the language, it's exactly the same: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8668591/regular-expression-all-characters-except-last-one

Comment: @Brian nope, indeed. But its simpler and cleaner, you know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This regex detects all but the last dot: `[.](?![\w]{2,4}$)`

Comment: This works and I'll accept it as answer, but I will use the regex that KennyTM showed.

Answer (score 3):

In addition to the other answers, here is one more

`[.](?!\d*$)`
or
`[.](?![^.]*$)`