# R: How to replace a dot between two characters in a string

Tags: regex, r, string

I am processing a lot of old text material. Quite often the OCR process puts a "." in a word, for example "t.h.i.s i.s a test." I want to replace these dots with an empty space "". But I do not want to get rid of the dots that indicate the end of a sentence. So I am looking for a regular expression that looks for letter/dot/letter and then replace the dot with nothing.

```
    test <- "t.h.i.s i.s a test." 
    gsub(test, pattern="\\w[[:punct:]]\\w", replacement="")
```

But this is the result

```
    ".  a test."
```

Any suggestions are appreciated.

Comment: This approach is not good: what if there is `5.6`?

Comment: From [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8747671/regex-remove-all-matches-leaving-the-last): `gsub("[\\.](?!\\d*$)", "", test, perl=TRUE)` works. Can someone familiar with regular expressions maybe explain why? (I can't)

Answer (score 2):

You can do the opposite, i.e. extract everything in the sentence that is not a dot in the middle of the string:

```
require(stringr)
test <- "t.h.i.s i.s a test." 
paste0(str_extract_all(test, "[^\\.]|(\\.$)")[[1]], collapse = "")

[1] "this is a test."
```

If you want to include the possibility of multiple sentences, and we can assume that a dot followed by a space is allowed, then you can use:

```
test <- "t.h.i.s i.s a test. With a.n.other sen.t.ence." 
paste0(str_extract_all(test, "[^\\.]|(\\.$)|(\\. )")[[1]], collapse = "")

[1] "this is a test. With another sentence."
```

Comment: Try `"T.h.i.s is a U.S. state."`. I do not think there is a 100% safe solution for the current problem.

Comment: Thanks. Could you show me how to do this with the gsub function. I am using lapply to use gsub over a large number of texts and using paste0 everything is put into a single text. But I am not sure how to transform your suggestion into the correct lapply command, what I have now is lapply(text, gsub, pattern="what to put here", replacement="")

Answer (score 2):

Here is my best guess, and a suggestion on how to further enhance the pattern:

```
> test = "T.h.i.s is a U.S. state. I drove 5.5 miles. Mr. Smith know English, French, etc. and can drive a car."
> gsub("\\b((?:U[.]S|etc|M(?:r?s|r))[.]||\\d+[.]\\d+)|[.](?!$|\\s+\\p{Lu})", "\\1", test, perl=T)
[1] "T.h.i.s is a U.S. state. I drove 5.5 miles. Mr. Smith know English, French, etc. and can drive a car."
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/iC1gM4/2)

*Explanation:*

- `\b((?:U[.]S|etc|M(?:r?s|r))[.]|\d+[.]\d+)` - match the exceptions that we will restore with a `\1` backreference in the replacement part. This part matches `U.S.`, `etc.`, `Mr.`, `Ms.`, `Mrs.`, `ditits+.digits` and *can be enhanced*
- `|` - or
- `[.](?!$|\s+\p{Lu})` - match a dot that is not followed by the end of the string (`$`) or 1+ whitespaces followed with an uppercase letter (`\s+\p{Lu}`)

Answer (score 1):

```
paste0(gsub('\\.', '', test), '.')
#[1] "this is a test."
```

To make this ugly to work with more sentences,

```
paste(paste0(gsub('\\.', '', unlist(strsplit(test, '\\. '))), '.'), collapse = ' ')
#[1] "this is a test. With another sentence."
```

Comment: And if there are several sentences in the input string?

Comment: Try `"T.h.i.s is a U.S. state."`. I do not think there is a 100% safe solution for the current problem.

Comment: I think you are right. Especially if there are also decimals...as you mentioned in comments