# RegEx to keep only the last dot from a string

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

How can I keep only last dot and remove every other dots from a string using preg_replace().

Example string:

```
1.000.000.00
```

Expected result:

```
1000000.00
```

My code:

```
$pattern = '/[^0-9\.]/';
$amount = '1.000.000.00';
echo preg_replace($pattern, "", $amount);
```

How do I solve this problem?

**Edit:**
Besides removing last dot in a number and removing any char that is not a digit or dot character from the string, I also need the dot removed, if it is present at the end of number like this,

```
1.000.000.00. after replacement should become 1.000.000.00
```

What should I do in addition to my current regex `[^0-9\.]` to achieve this?

Comment: Welcome to SO. What have you tried? You should show your code, this site is to help with your code, not write it for you.

Comment: @FunkDoc 
Added the code i have

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/8748060/3832970

Comment: Ok. Will give it a try

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew: This post has many requirements that are not same as linked post. Some requirements were discussed with me while I was solving his post, which I've also updated in the post. Please revert and unmark the post as duplicate.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use this regex to match all dots except the last one and replace it with empty string,

```
\.(?=.*\.)
```

Here `\.` matches a dot only if it sees a dot ahead in the string using positive look ahead `(?=.*\.)`

**[Regex Demo](https://regex101.com/r/DflQTL/1)**

**[PHP Code demo](https://rextester.com/GCM64460)**

```
$s = '1.000.000.00';
echo preg_replace('/\.(?=.*\.)/', '', $s);
```

Prints,

```
1000000.00
```

---

**Edit 1:**

Need to use OP's current regex too in conjunction with this as OP seems to replace every other thing that is not a digit or a dot to be replaced with empty string as well. The combined regex you can use is this, which will also remove any non-digit and dot (unless it is not the last dot),

```
[^0-9.]+|\.(?=.*\.)
```

**[Regex Demo for combined regex with OP's regex](https://regex101.com/r/DflQTL/2)**

---

**Edit 2:**

Also, for handling cases like below where an unneeded dot is present at the end of number like `1.000.000.` should also be removed but the last dot within the number should be retained.

The regex needs to be modified to following for handling this case as well,

```
[^0-9.]+|\.(?=\d+\.\d+|$)
```

**[Regex Demo handling dot at the end of number](https://regex101.com/r/DflQTL/3)**

Comment: Can you make it work with my pattern? Because the string will be filtered only digits and last dot.

Comment: @JosephMurphy: Sure, just few moments.

Comment: @JosephMurphy: Updated. I hope this is what you were looking for? Let me know in case you wanted something else or have any further queries.

Comment: One other thing I forgot to mention Kumar, what if the string will be:
"1.000.000."

And how can i limit only by maximum 2 decimals?
If no decimal is present, all dots needs to be removed.

I don't have any experience with regular expressions. That would be all if you can help me.

Comment: @JosephMurphy: You want me to handle that case as well where if the number has a dot at the end and it should get removed but the last dot within number shouldn't get replaced right? Ok, just few moments.

Comment: @JosephMurphy: Updated again. Please check and let me know if this looks fine.

Comment: Yes Kumar, now its perfect.

Comment: @Kumar your solution works perfect! I have modified your regex just to apply for number with dot, but not for last. 
`\d\.(?=.*\.)`