# The last dot (.) should not be removed

Tags: java, regex

```
public static void main(String[] args) {


    String body = "Rs. 199.32.test";

    System.out.println(body);

    body = body.replaceAll("\\d+[,\\\\./-[0-9]*]*\\d*", "xxxxx");

    System.out.println(body);

    }
```

Current Output is `Rs. xxxxxtest`
Desired Output is `Rs. xxxxx.test`

I have not been able to update the using regex to get the desired result.I don't want to replace the last dot after the decimal points.

Comment: use this instead `body = body.replaceAll("\\d+[,\\\\./-[0-9]*]*\\d*\\.", "xxxxx\\.");`

Comment: Duplicate question [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8668591/regular-expression-all-characters-except-last-one)

Comment: @Srini this is not duplicate of the link you have given.I don't want to match all dots except the last one. Try to understand the question first.

Comment: @ritesht93 I dont want to change the replace value.I want to change the expression only.

Comment: Do you want to remove dot only between numbers?

Comment: @rock321987 that logic might work as all of my strings are of that pattern only.

Comment: @MithunDebnath something like **[this](https://regex101.com/r/tR7mJ5/1)**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will work

```
String body = "Rs. 199.32.test";
System.out.println(body.replaceAll("(\\d+)(?:(?:\\.)(\\d+))?", "$1$2"));
```

**[Ideone Demo](http://ideone.com/rcSCzK)**

**[Regex Demo](https://regex101.com/r/tR7mJ5/2)**

Answer (score 0):

You can do it something like below.

```
public class Main {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    String body = "Rs. 199.32.test";
    System.out.println(body);
    body = body.replaceAll(body.substring(0,body.lastIndexOf('.')), "xxxxx");
    System.out.println(body);
  }
}
```

Comment: I don't want to replace the entire string.

Comment: It is not replacing the entire the entire string. It will only replace `199.32`.

Comment: It will replace the Rs. too as you are taking the sub string size from zero.The output will be  xxxxx.test not Rs. xxxx.test.body=body.replaceAll("(\\d+)(?:(?:\\.)(\\d+))?", "xxxx"); is working fine. body = body.replaceAll("\\d+[,\\\\./-[0-9]*]*\\d*\\.", "%d\\."); was also helpful.