# How to replace all occurrence other than last occurrence and characters other than (a-zA-Z0-9) in single regex java

Tags: java, regex, string

I have string like `test.e$xamp[le.test.csv`

I need output as `test_e_xamp_le_test.csv`

Now i want to replace all `.` occurrence other than last `.` occurrence and characters occurrence other than (`a-zA-Z0-9`) with `_` using regex.

Currently I am using below regex but it replacing all `.` occurrence with `_`

```
str = str.replaceAll("[^a-zA-Z0-9.]", "_");
```

Is it possible to achieve both condition in single regex?

Comment: duplicate question, try [regex match all except last one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8668641/8841790)

Answer (score 5):

You could use the regexp `\\.(?=.*\\.)`

Sample:

```
String str = "test.example.test.csv".replaceAll("\\.(?=.*\\.)", "_");
System.out.println(str);
```

Output:

```
test_example_test.csv
```

Comment: can we add other character also replace in same regex ?

Comment: Like other than last . and charter other than (a-zA-Z0-9) ?

Comment: Very sweet regex!!! +1 (I wish I could vote more than once for this one)

Comment: @rajesh yes you can use `str = str.replaceAll("[^a-zA-Z0-9](?=.*[^a-zA-Z0-9])", "_");`

Comment: @YCF_L Its working perfect !!!

Comment: Thanks for answering @YCF_L.

Comment: ..no problem :)

Answer (score 1):

You can also, instead of using regex, go for a solution like this one, where you **split** and **recombine** the intermediate strings:

```
String input = "test.example.test.csv";
String[] tmp = input.split("\\P{Alnum}");
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
String del = "";
for (int i = 0; i < tmp.length - 1; i++) {
    sb.append(del).append(tmp[i]);
    del = "_";
}
sb.append(".").append(tmp[tmp.length - 1]);

System.out.println(sb.toString());
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
test_example_test.csv
```

Comment: @Lino: You are completely right, I wanted to remove the `tmp` variable to save some memory but it will slow down the whole loop!!! I have regrouped the 2 appends operation in one in the loop... I don't know if we can do much better any idea?